# How do I overlap identical UV islands so they share the same texture?

Tags: uv, faces, uv-image-editor

I have the simple model pictured below and would like to UV map it in a way in which many of the UV islands generated from the seams, will get the same texture and therefore should exist in the same space within the UV map.  For example the outer "wall" will have the same texture all the way around, but in several different UV Islands.  How can I effectively unwrap the UVs so that identical islands overlap as one in the UV map export?

[image]

Comment: Please see this answer which shows moving UV islands to be on top of each other.   http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43665/have-multiple-parts-of-model-share-same-uv-texture/43666#43666